# How can I query the World Bank Microdata REST API in R?

Tags: r, rest, httr

I am trying to query the [World Bank Microdata API](https://microdata.worldbank.org/api-documentation/catalog/index.html#) from within R, using the [httr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/index.html) package. Unfortunately, I couldn't find much guidance on how to do this. According to Microdata REST API documentation, the path to search in the catalog is http://microdata.worldbank.org/index.php/api/catalog/search, and the relevant path parameters are

```
{
"idno": "string",
"title": "string",
"nation": "string",
"created": "2022-06-16T06:24:40Z",
"changed": "2022-06-16T06:24:40Z"
}
```

The minimum working example below attempts to extract information on items from Malawi only. To this end, I set `nation = "malawi"` and leave the other arguments empty. I also tried `nation = "Malawi"` (with capital M) and `nation = "mwi"` (the iso country code). Either way, `status_code(r)` yields 200, which indicates that the request was successful. Yet, the output from `str()` clearly shows that we have items from Afghanistan, not Malawi. My hunch is that the `nation` parameter is not specified correctly and the response from the API yields the first few of ALL its entries, starting with the country that's ranked first alphabetically - Afghanistan.

```r
library(httr)

r <- GET("http://microdata.worldbank.org/index.php/api/catalog/search",
         query = list(idno = "", title = "", nation = "malawi", created = "", changed = ""))

status_code(r)
#> [1] 200

str(content(r))
#> List of 1
#>  $ result:List of 7
#>   ..$ rows                 :List of 15
#>   .. ..$ :List of 19
#>   .. .. ..$ id              : int 4302
#>   .. .. ..$ idno            : chr "AFG_2020_VOLREP_v01_M"
#>   .. .. ..$ type            : chr "survey"
#>   .. .. ..$ title           : chr "Voluntary Repatriation 2020"
#>   .. .. ..$ nation          : chr "Afghanistan"
#>   .. .. ..$ authoring_entity: chr "UNHCR"
#>   .. .. ..$ form_model      : chr "remote"
#>   .. .. ..$ data_class_id   : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ year_start      : int 2020
#>   .. .. ..$ year_end        : int 2020
#>   .. .. ..$ repositoryid    : chr "unhcr"
#>   .. .. ..$ repo_title      : chr "United Nations Refugee Agency (UNHCR)"
#>   .. .. ..$ created         : chr "2022-03-14T12:05:12-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ changed         : chr "2022-03-14T12:31:03-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ total_views     : int 1050
#>   .. .. ..$ total_downloads : int 42
#>   .. .. ..$ varcount        : int 11
#>   .. .. ..$ thumbnail       : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ url             : chr "https://microdata.worldbank.org/index.php/catalog/4302"
#>   .. ..$ :List of 19
#>   .. .. ..$ id              : int 4018
#>   .. .. ..$ idno            : chr "AFG_2021_WBCS_v01_M"
#>   .. .. ..$ type            : chr "survey"
#>   .. .. ..$ title           : chr "World Bank Group Country Survey 2021"
#>   .. .. ..$ nation          : chr "Afghanistan"
#>   .. .. ..$ authoring_entity: chr "Public Opinion Research Group"
#>   .. .. ..$ form_model      : chr "direct"
#>   .. .. ..$ data_class_id   : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ year_start      : int 2020
#>   .. .. ..$ year_end        : int 2021
#>   .. .. ..$ repositoryid    : chr "COS"
#>   .. .. ..$ repo_title      : chr "The World Bank Group Country Opinion Survey Program (COS)"
#>   .. .. ..$ created         : chr "2021-06-01T15:41:49-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ changed         : chr "2021-06-01T15:47:09-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ total_views     : int 11245
#>   .. .. ..$ total_downloads : int 907
#>   .. .. ..$ varcount        : int 418
#>   .. .. ..$ thumbnail       : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ url             : chr "https://microdata.worldbank.org/index.php/catalog/4018"
#>   .. ..$ :List of 19
#>   .. .. ..$ id              : int 4346
#>   .. .. ..$ idno            : chr "AFG_2019_LIS_v01_M"
#>   .. .. ..$ type            : chr "survey"
#>   .. .. ..$ title           : chr "Livelihoods Programme Monitoring Beneficiary Survey 2019"
#>   .. .. ..$ nation          : chr "Afghanistan"
#>   .. .. ..$ authoring_entity: chr "UN Refugee Agency (UNHCR)"
#>   .. .. ..$ form_model      : chr "remote"
#>   .. .. ..$ data_class_id   : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ year_start      : int 2019
#>   .. .. ..$ year_end        : int 2019
#>   .. .. ..$ repositoryid    : chr "unhcr"
#>   .. .. ..$ repo_title      : chr "United Nations Refugee Agency (UNHCR)"
#>   .. .. ..$ created         : chr "2022-03-22T11:52:01-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ changed         : chr "2022-04-13T11:24:04-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ total_views     : int 848
#>   .. .. ..$ total_downloads : int 18
#>   .. .. ..$ varcount        : int 134
#>   .. .. ..$ thumbnail       : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ url             : chr "https://microdata.worldbank.org/index.php/catalog/4346"
#>   .. ..$ :List of 19
#>   .. .. ..$ id              : int 4303
#>   .. .. ..$ idno            : chr "AFG_2019_VOLREP_v01_M"
#>   .. .. ..$ type            : chr "survey"
#>   .. .. ..$ title           : chr "Voluntary Repatriation 2019"
#>   .. .. ..$ nation          : chr "Afghanistan"
#>   .. .. ..$ authoring_entity: chr "UNHCR"
#>   .. .. ..$ form_model      : chr "remote"
#>   .. .. ..$ data_class_id   : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ year_start      : int 2019
#>   .. .. ..$ year_end        : int 2019
#>   .. .. ..$ repositoryid    : chr "unhcr"
#>   .. .. ..$ repo_title      : chr "United Nations Refugee Agency (UNHCR)"
#>   .. .. ..$ created         : chr "2022-03-14T12:29:41-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ changed         : chr "2022-03-14T12:31:04-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ total_views     : int 370
#>   .. .. ..$ total_downloads : int 34
#>   .. .. ..$ varcount        : int 11
#>   .. .. ..$ thumbnail       : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ url             : chr "https://microdata.worldbank.org/index.php/catalog/4303"
#>   .. ..$ :List of 19
#>   .. .. ..$ id              : int 3645
#>   .. .. ..$ idno            : chr "AFG_2018_SPA_v01_M"
#>   .. .. ..$ type            : chr "survey"
#>   .. .. ..$ title           : chr "Service Provision Assessment Survey 2018-2019"
#>   .. .. ..$ nation          : chr "Afghanistan"
#>   .. .. ..$ authoring_entity: chr "Ministry of Public Health"
#>   .. .. ..$ form_model      : chr "remote"
#>   .. .. ..$ data_class_id   : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ year_start      : int 2018
#>   .. .. ..$ year_end        : int 2019
#>   .. .. ..$ repositoryid    : chr "dhs"
#>   .. .. ..$ repo_title      : chr "MEASURE DHS: Demographic and Health Surveys"
#>   .. .. ..$ created         : chr "2020-03-17T15:38:39-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ changed         : chr "2020-03-17T15:44:27-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ total_views     : int 7132
#>   .. .. ..$ total_downloads : int 0
#>   .. .. ..$ varcount        : int 0
#>   .. .. ..$ thumbnail       : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ url             : chr "https://microdata.worldbank.org/index.php/catalog/3645"
#>   .. ..$ :List of 19
#>   .. .. ..$ id              : int 4304
#>   .. .. ..$ idno            : chr "AFG_2018_VOLREP_v01_M"
#>   .. .. ..$ type            : chr "survey"
#>   .. .. ..$ title           : chr "Voluntary Repatriation 2018"
#>   .. .. ..$ nation          : chr "Afghanistan"
#>   .. .. ..$ authoring_entity: chr "UNHCR"
#>   .. .. ..$ form_model      : chr "remote"
#>   .. .. ..$ data_class_id   : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ year_start      : int 2018
#>   .. .. ..$ year_end        : int 2018
#>   .. .. ..$ repositoryid    : chr "unhcr"
#>   .. .. ..$ repo_title      : chr "United Nations Refugee Agency (UNHCR)"
#>   .. .. ..$ created         : chr "2022-03-14T12:31:05-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ changed         : chr "2022-03-14T12:31:05-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ total_views     : int 325
#>   .. .. ..$ total_downloads : int 39
#>   .. .. ..$ varcount        : int 11
#>   .. .. ..$ thumbnail       : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ url             : chr "https://microdata.worldbank.org/index.php/catalog/4304"
#>   .. ..$ :List of 19
#>   .. .. ..$ id              : int 3192
#>   .. .. ..$ idno            : chr "AFG_2018_WBCS_v01_M"
#>   .. .. ..$ type            : chr "survey"
#>   .. .. ..$ title           : chr "World Bank Group Country Survey 2018"
#>   .. .. ..$ nation          : chr "Afghanistan"
#>   .. .. ..$ authoring_entity: chr "Public Opinion Research Group"
#>   .. .. ..$ form_model      : chr "direct"
#>   .. .. ..$ data_class_id   : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ year_start      : int 2018
#>   .. .. ..$ year_end        : int 2018
#>   .. .. ..$ repositoryid    : chr "COS"
#>   .. .. ..$ repo_title      : chr "The World Bank Group Country Opinion Survey Program (COS)"
#>   .. .. ..$ created         : chr "2018-09-12T10:42:16-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ changed         : chr "2019-08-16T10:48:25-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ total_views     : int 76106
#>   .. .. ..$ total_downloads : int 21800
#>   .. .. ..$ varcount        : int 442
#>   .. .. ..$ thumbnail       : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ url             : chr "https://microdata.worldbank.org/index.php/catalog/3192"
#>   .. ..$ :List of 19
#>   .. .. ..$ id              : int 3246
#>   .. .. ..$ idno            : chr "AFG_2017_FINDEX_v02_M"
#>   .. .. ..$ type            : chr "survey"
#>   .. .. ..$ title           : chr "Global Financial Inclusion (Global Findex) Database 2017"
#>   .. .. ..$ nation          : chr "Afghanistan"
#>   .. .. ..$ authoring_entity: chr "Development Research Group, Finance and Private Sector Development Unit"
#>   .. .. ..$ form_model      : chr "public"
#>   .. .. ..$ data_class_id   : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ year_start      : int 2017
#>   .. .. ..$ year_end        : int 2017
#>   .. .. ..$ repositoryid    : chr "global-findex"
#>   .. .. ..$ repo_title      : chr "Global Financial Inclusion (Global Findex) Database"
#>   .. .. ..$ created         : chr "2018-10-18T17:06:58-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ changed         : chr "2018-10-31T13:28:32-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ total_views     : int 32264
#>   .. .. ..$ total_downloads : int 4092
#>   .. .. ..$ varcount        : int 103
#>   .. .. ..$ thumbnail       : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ url             : chr "https://microdata.worldbank.org/index.php/catalog/3246"
#>   .. ..$ :List of 19
#>   .. .. ..$ id              : int 3414
#>   .. .. ..$ idno            : chr "AFG_2017_SABER-SD_v01_M"
#>   .. .. ..$ type            : chr "survey"
#>   .. .. ..$ title           : chr "SABER Service Delivery 2017, Measuring Education Service Delivery"
#>   .. .. ..$ nation          : chr "Afghanistan"
#>   .. .. ..$ authoring_entity: chr "World Bank"
#>   .. .. ..$ form_model      : chr "public"
#>   .. .. ..$ data_class_id   : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ year_start      : int 2017
#>   .. .. ..$ year_end        : int 2017
#>   .. .. ..$ repositoryid    : chr "central"
#>   .. .. ..$ repo_title      : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ created         : chr "2019-03-04T13:28:59-05:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ changed         : chr "2019-06-11T10:43:31-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ total_views     : int 51844
#>   .. .. ..$ total_downloads : int 12549
#>   .. .. ..$ varcount        : int 1424
#>   .. .. ..$ thumbnail       : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ url             : chr "https://microdata.worldbank.org/index.php/catalog/3414"
#>   .. ..$ :List of 19
#>   .. .. ..$ id              : int 3998
#>   .. .. ..$ idno            : chr "AFG_2017_SEA-HER_v01_M"
#>   .. .. ..$ type            : chr "survey"
#>   .. .. ..$ title           : chr "Socio-Economic Assessment of IDPS and Returnees in the Five Most Populated Settlements of Afghanistan's Herat Province 2017"
#>   .. .. ..$ nation          : chr "Afghanistan"
#>   .. .. ..$ authoring_entity: chr "United Nations High Commissioner for Refugees (UNHCR)"
#>   .. .. ..$ form_model      : chr "remote"
#>   .. .. ..$ data_class_id   : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ year_start      : int 2017
#>   .. .. ..$ year_end        : int 2017
#>   .. .. ..$ repositoryid    : chr "unhcr"
#>   .. .. ..$ repo_title      : chr "United Nations Refugee Agency (UNHCR)"
#>   .. .. ..$ created         : chr "2021-05-21T18:44:10-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ changed         : chr "2021-05-21T18:44:37-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ total_views     : int 3388
#>   .. .. ..$ total_downloads : int 0
#>   .. .. ..$ varcount        : int 185
#>   .. .. ..$ thumbnail       : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ url             : chr "https://microdata.worldbank.org/index.php/catalog/3998"
#>   .. ..$ :List of 19
#>   .. .. ..$ id              : int 3997
#>   .. .. ..$ idno            : chr "AFG_2017_SEA-KHO_v01_M"
#>   .. .. ..$ type            : chr "survey"
#>   .. .. ..$ title           : chr "Socio-Economic Assessment of Pakistani Refugees in Afghanistan's Khost and Paktika Provinces 2017"
#>   .. .. ..$ nation          : chr "Afghanistan"
#>   .. .. ..$ authoring_entity: chr "United Nations High Commissioner for Refugees (UNHCR)"
#>   .. .. ..$ form_model      : chr "remote"
#>   .. .. ..$ data_class_id   : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ year_start      : int 2017
#>   .. .. ..$ year_end        : int 2017
#>   .. .. ..$ repositoryid    : chr "unhcr"
#>   .. .. ..$ repo_title      : chr "United Nations Refugee Agency (UNHCR)"
#>   .. .. ..$ created         : chr "2021-05-21T18:40:58-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ changed         : chr "2021-05-21T18:41:30-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ total_views     : int 2965
#>   .. .. ..$ total_downloads : int 0
#>   .. .. ..$ varcount        : int 186
#>   .. .. ..$ thumbnail       : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ url             : chr "https://microdata.worldbank.org/index.php/catalog/3997"
#>   .. ..$ :List of 19
#>   .. .. ..$ id              : int 4305
#>   .. .. ..$ idno            : chr "AFG_2016_VOLREP_v01_M"
#>   .. .. ..$ type            : chr "survey"
#>   .. .. ..$ title           : chr "Voluntary Repatriation 2016"
#>   .. .. ..$ nation          : chr "Afghanistan"
#>   .. .. ..$ authoring_entity: chr "UNHCR"
#>   .. .. ..$ form_model      : chr "remote"
#>   .. .. ..$ data_class_id   : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ year_start      : int 2016
#>   .. .. ..$ year_end        : int 2016
#>   .. .. ..$ repositoryid    : chr "unhcr"
#>   .. .. ..$ repo_title      : chr "United Nations Refugee Agency (UNHCR)"
#>   .. .. ..$ created         : chr "2022-03-14T12:31:05-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ changed         : chr "2022-03-14T12:31:05-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ total_views     : int 318
#>   .. .. ..$ total_downloads : int 32
#>   .. .. ..$ varcount        : int 11
#>   .. .. ..$ thumbnail       : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ url             : chr "https://microdata.worldbank.org/index.php/catalog/4305"
#>   .. ..$ :List of 19
#>   .. .. ..$ id              : int 2786
#>   .. .. ..$ idno            : chr "AFG_2015_DHS_v01_M"
#>   .. .. ..$ type            : chr "survey"
#>   .. .. ..$ title           : chr "Demographic and Health Survey 2015"
#>   .. .. ..$ nation          : chr "Afghanistan"
#>   .. .. ..$ authoring_entity: chr "Central Statistics Organization (CSO), Ministry of Public Health (MoPH)"
#>   .. .. ..$ form_model      : chr "remote"
#>   .. .. ..$ data_class_id   : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ year_start      : int 2015
#>   .. .. ..$ year_end        : int 2016
#>   .. .. ..$ repositoryid    : chr "dhs"
#>   .. .. ..$ repo_title      : chr "MEASURE DHS: Demographic and Health Surveys"
#>   .. .. ..$ created         : chr "2017-02-27T13:40:30-05:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ changed         : chr "2017-05-23T13:37:01-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ total_views     : int 191840
#>   .. .. ..$ total_downloads : int 3375
#>   .. .. ..$ varcount        : int 2429
#>   .. .. ..$ thumbnail       : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ url             : chr "https://microdata.worldbank.org/index.php/catalog/2786"
#>   .. ..$ :List of 19
#>   .. .. ..$ id              : int 3651
#>   .. .. ..$ idno            : chr "AFG_2015_DHS_v01_M_v01_A_IPUMS"
#>   .. .. ..$ type            : chr "survey"
#>   .. .. ..$ title           : chr "Demographic and Health Survey 2015 - IPUMS Subset"
#>   .. .. ..$ nation          : chr "Afghanistan"
#>   .. .. ..$ authoring_entity: chr "Central Statistics Organization (CSO) [Afghanistan], Ministry of Public Health (MoPH) [Afghanistan], and ICF., "| __truncated__
#>   .. .. ..$ form_model      : chr "remote"
#>   .. .. ..$ data_class_id   : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ year_start      : int 2015
#>   .. .. ..$ year_end        : int 2015
#>   .. .. ..$ repositoryid    : chr "ipums"
#>   .. .. ..$ repo_title      : chr "Integrated Public Use Microdata Series (IPUMS)"
#>   .. .. ..$ created         : chr "2020-05-01T13:29:51-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ changed         : chr "2020-05-14T13:38:12-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ total_views     : int 50559
#>   .. .. ..$ total_downloads : int 0
#>   .. .. ..$ varcount        : int 3829
#>   .. .. ..$ thumbnail       : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ url             : chr "https://microdata.worldbank.org/index.php/catalog/3651"
#>   .. ..$ :List of 19
#>   .. .. ..$ id              : int 4306
#>   .. .. ..$ idno            : chr "AFG_2015_VOLREP_v01_M"
#>   .. .. ..$ type            : chr "survey"
#>   .. .. ..$ title           : chr "Voluntary Repatriation 2015"
#>   .. .. ..$ nation          : chr "Afghanistan"
#>   .. .. ..$ authoring_entity: chr "UNHCR"
#>   .. .. ..$ form_model      : chr "remote"
#>   .. .. ..$ data_class_id   : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ year_start      : int 2015
#>   .. .. ..$ year_end        : int 2015
#>   .. .. ..$ repositoryid    : chr "unhcr"
#>   .. .. ..$ repo_title      : chr "United Nations Refugee Agency (UNHCR)"
#>   .. .. ..$ created         : chr "2022-03-14T12:31:06-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ changed         : chr "2022-03-14T12:31:06-04:00"
#>   .. .. ..$ total_views     : int 308
#>   .. .. ..$ total_downloads : int 23
#>   .. .. ..$ varcount        : int 11
#>   .. .. ..$ thumbnail       : NULL
#>   .. .. ..$ url             : chr "https://microdata.worldbank.org/index.php/catalog/4306"
#>   ..$ found                : int 3854
#>   ..$ total                : int 3854
#>   ..$ limit                : int 15
#>   ..$ offset               : int 0
#>   ..$ search_counts_by_type:List of 1
#>   .. ..$ survey: int 3854
#>   ..$ page                 : int 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong and how these search criteria, specified [here](https://microdata.worldbank.org/api-documentation/catalog/index.html#operation/SingleCollection) in JSON, should be used in R? Cheers in advance...

Comment: The mircodata-api is a bit confusing, but you want to set the path parameters, ie. you need to replace `nation` with `country`, like so: `GET("http://microdata.worldbank.org/index.php/api/catalog/search", query = list(country = "malawi", ...))`

Comment: Expanding on `...`, would make a useful answer, across a couple of `...` examples.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan. Thanks for your comment; wow, it works now! The documentation includes some seemingly contradictory parameter specs (like nation vs. country). I agree with @Chris that it would be super helpful if you and others could elaborate on the `...` in case you got more gotchas about this API up your sleeve. No pressure though. Cheers

Comment: Great if it helped you; `...` was meant as a placeholder, which is not very helpful in the R-context (and I couldn't edit the comment as it was already upvoted), sorry about that

Comment: One example: the field `id` also does not work. In the exact same context as above, consider the call `r <- GET("http://microdata.worldbank.org/index.php/api/catalog/search",query = list(collection = "lsms", id = "4322", inc_iso = TRUE))`. It correctly returns only entries from the LSMS collection and adds the iso3 country code. `id`, however, refers to a 2019 study from Kenya specifically - yet I get items from all kinds of places.